# Presto epoch string to timestamp

Tags: presto

Require your help as stuck in time conversion in presto.

I have a epoch column with name timestamp as a string datatype and i want to convert this into date timestamp.

I have used the below query after reading through various blogs:

```
SELECT date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(CAST(timestamp AS bigint)) AS date ,
        '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ'))
FROM wqmparquet;
```

Everytime i run this query i get an error:

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2020-04-27T19:49:50.000Z" is malformed at "T19:49:50.000Z"

Can somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I might be oversimplifying this, but if you want to convert an epoch string to a `timestamp` datatype, you can just do:

```
from_unixtime(cast(timestamp as bigint))
```

You can generate a `timestamp with time zone` by passing a second argument to [`from_unixtime()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime), as a time zone string.

Comment: Hi GMB- Thanks for help. With the above query i am able to get the time till seconds. I also want milliseconds. When i modified my query and ran :select from_unixtime(cast(timestamp as bigint),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%fZ') as d from wqm order by d; i get an error NOT_SUPPORTED: Time zone not supported: %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%fZ. Can you please help on this ? Basically i get this 1970-01-01 00:00:29.000 but actual is 1970-01-01 00:00:29.423